# Is a LinkedHashMap basically a LinkedList with O(1) 'contains'?

Tags: java, list

I'm facing a micro-optimisation where I'm calling `contains` frequenly on a **LinkedList**. Would it be a good idea to just change it to a **LinkedHashMap**?

Note: I'm only adding and checking if the list contains a certain value.

Comment: What order do you need? A List can have any order you set but LinkedHashMap can only have insertion or access order. If you don't need an order and don't have duplicates, you can use any Set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bit more complex then "just a `LinkedList` with average-case `O(1)` contains", but essentially - functionality speaking yes.

A `LinkedHashMap` allows `O(1)` contains, and keeps elements in order they were inserted - same as a `LinkedList`.  You might also want to have a look on [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

**However**, you might be facing problems if you will want **duplicate entries**. A `LinkedHashMap` and `LinkedHashSet` are implementing `Set` and `Map` interfaces, and not the `List` interface, so they do not allow duplicates.

Comment: Or a LinkedHashSet if there is only the value and not a key=value. Assuming you don't have duplicate values.

Comment: @shonkylinuxuser: Yeap, brought the link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a LinkedHashMap provides O(1) membership checks

> Like HashMap, it provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (add, contains and remove) assuming the hash function disperses elements properly among the buckets.

Note also

> Performance is likely to be just slightly below that of HashMap, due to the added expense of maintaining the linked list, with one exception: Iteration over the collection-views of a LinkedHashMap requires time proportional to the size of the map, regardless of its capacity. Iteration over a HashMap is likely to be more expensive, requiring time proportional to its capacity.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

If you don't need predictable ordering, a HashMap will be slightly faster on insertion/modification because it does not need to maintain the linked list to preserve ordering.

Answer (score 0):

No; a `LinkedList` is a `List`, while a `LinkedHashMap` is a `Map`.

Aside from that, `LinkedHashMap` does **not** guarantee O(1) contains; in fact, `LinkedHashMap.contains` is O(n). Constant-time `contains` is possible if using perfect hashing or a (roughly) uniform distribution of keys to buckets (i.e. best-case), but in a scenario with collisions, it is average-case linear-time with a constant factor 0 < *k* < 1.

What you seem to want is an insertion-order `Set` with average-case performance comparable to `HashMap.contains`, so I suggest you look at [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

> This implementation differs from `HashSet` in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (*insertion-order*).

Comment: Though any hash solution does not **guarantee** `O(1)` contains - it does provide an **average** `O(1)` `contains()` with a decent hash function. This is due to the fact that the java implementation maintains load factor in the hash table implementation, which causes a constant number of collision - on average. The probability of getting a linear performance with a decent hash functions are slim (though exists).

Comment: @amit indeed, but I think it's important to make the distinction between average-case and worst-case lower bound ;) Getting O(n) with a k = 1 is *extremely* unlikely (at least in OpenJDK where `HashMap` uses a mixing function), but moderate clustering (k < 1) due to naive choice of `hashCode` is not -- and given the OP was comparing a `List` to a `Map`, I figured it's important to make that distinction. :p